# float next div wraps around

Tags: css

I'm having problem with this style, the content body wraps around the menu bar, I've tried removing the float but nothing happens.

```
.menu {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
.menu ul {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
}
.menu li a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #666666;
    border-left: 1px;
    border-right: 1px;
    box-shadow: #333 3px 3px 4px;
}
.content {
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

the content writes next the last link.

Comment: Could you please also give us your HTML code alongside with the CSS? Best case scenario would be if you could provide a JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes some HTML would be good please. We cannot just assume how your page layout is and try to throw out random solutions that may or may not work because we cannot see what is going on with the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `clear` in your CSS. Make sure that the first element after the floating div gets cleared.

Comment: It's just that the CSS for these elements has different default values. Reset those and there's no more differences in display. There are however, the differences in _semantics_.